# Correct way for fisheye images undistortion

Tags: c++, opencv

I've done some sample program that removes lens distortion from the chessboard like fish eye images, and it works ok, here's the screen shot

[image]

Next I wanted to use the fish eye chessboard pattern (right image above) in order to remove the same lens distortion but from the real image and had no luck - the curvature still remains on the undistorted image,
thus I got this instead

[image]

the code

```
void getObjectPoints(cv::Size, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>>&);

bool getImagePoints(cv::Mat&, cv::Size&, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>>&);

void runCalibration(cv::Mat& image, cv::Matx33d&, cv::Vec4d&);

cv::Mat removeFisheyeLensDist(cv::Mat&, cv::Matx33d&, cv::Vec4d&);

// ... definitions    
void getObjectPoints(cv::Size patternSize, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>>& objectPoints)
{
    const float squareSize = 0.0015f;
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> knownBoardPositions;
    for (int i = 0; i < patternSize.height; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < patternSize.width; ++j)
        {
            knownBoardPositions.push_back(cv::Point3f(j*squareSize, i*squareSize, 0.0f));
        }
    }
    if (knownBoardPositions.size() > 0)
        objectPoints.push_back(knownBoardPositions);
}

bool getImagePoints(cv::Mat& image, cv::Size& patternSize, std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>>& imagePoints)
{
    bool patternFound = false;
    while (!patternFound)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
        for (int i = 7; i <= 30; ++i)
        {
            int w = i;
            int h = i - 2;

            patternFound = cv::findChessboardCorners(image, cv::Size(w, h), corners,
                                              cv::CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | cv::CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);
            if (patternFound)
            {
                patternSize.width = w;
                patternSize.height = h;
                imagePoints.push_back(corners);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return patternFound;
}

void runCalibration(cv::Mat& image, cv::Matx33d& K, cv::Vec4d& D)
{
    std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point2f> > imagePoints;
    std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point3f> > objectPoints;
    cv::Size patternSize;
    bool patternFound = getImagePoints(image, patternSize, imagePoints);

    if (patternFound)
    {
        getObjectPoints(patternSize, objectPoints);

        std::vector<cv::Vec3d> rvecs;
        std::vector<cv::Vec3d> tvecs;
        cv::fisheye::calibrate(
            objectPoints,
            imagePoints,
            image.size(),
            K,
            D,
            rvecs,
            tvecs,
            cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_SKEW |   cv::fisheye::CALIB_RECOMPUTE_EXTRINSIC
        |   cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K1   |   cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K2
        |   cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K3   |   cv::fisheye::CALIB_FIX_K4
//            cv::TermCriteria(3, 20, 1e-6)
        );
    }
}

cv::Mat removeFisheyeLensDist(cv::Mat& distorted, cv::Matx33d& K, cv::Vec4d& D)
{
    cv::Mat undistorted;
    cv::Matx33d newK = K;
    cv::fisheye::undistortImage(distorted, undistorted, K, D, newK);
    return undistorted;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat chessBoardPattern = //..
    cv::Mat distortedImage = //...
    cv::imshow("distorted", distortedImage);

    cv::Matx33d K;  cv::Vec4d D;
    runCalibration(chessBoardPattern, K, D);
    cv::Mat undistoredImage = removeFisheyeLensDist(distortedImage, K, D);    
    cv::imshow("undistored", undistoredImage);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

As I think the image with the tower has very simillar curvatures as a chessboard on the right so the same pattern should've work for tower image ...

What Am I doing wrong there ?
And Why it's not fixing lens distortion for the tower image ?

Comment: why no answers/comments ? too much code ?

Comment: Were the image above (chessboard) and below (Eiffel tower) taken using a same camera?

Comment: @alexisrozhkov sorry I'm not able to understand your question

Comment: Fixed the typo in comment above. To clarify further, I meant - have you used same camera to capture image with chessboard and image with tower? If not - this explains why the undistortion is not correct.

Comment: @alexisrozhkov no, cameras are different for those images. I just thought if images have same curvatures thus the camera parameters should be approximately same and so I can undistort fisheye emage with a chessboard pattern

Comment: @alexisrozhkov what is the algorithm for removing fish eye effect on a Eiffel tower image then ? (i'm new to computer vision and opencv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately your assumption

> if images have same curvatures thus the camera parameters should be approximately same and so I can undistort fisheye emage with a chessboard pattern

is wrong. Even cameras of same model will have differences in focal distance, lens geometry and placement, etc, which need to be calibrated individually. Besides during usage of camera these parameters may change due to heating, vibration and other effects (usually this is ignored in practice).

To undistort your image without having access to camera all you can do is just select some simple fisheye camera model and try to estimate parameters manually, trying to make straight lines look straight (for example using GUI with sliders for all parameters). This can be tedious, but I am not aware of better options. Besides, some image editing software may have tools for that (if I recall correctly GIMP does)

Comment: does this mean that I can't undistort some random fish eye image (lets say downloaded from internet) for which I don't know any camera parameters ?

Comment: Like I said above, even if it's possible to do automatically using a single image of a generic scene from  unknown camera - I am not aware of such algorithms.