# BoofCV. Correction fish-eye image

Tags: java, fisheye, boofcv

I'm making a application to correction fish-eye images using library BoofCV. I have found an [example](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Fisheye_To_Pinhole) but I don't know how to show all the correction image after correction like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188989/correct-way-for-fisheye-images-undistortion)

```
    static public BufferedImage calibrationCircular(BufferedImage image, CameraUniversalOmni fisheyeModel) {
    logger.info("Called function calibrationCircular()");
    // Specify what the pinhole camera should look like
    CameraPinhole pinholeModel = new CameraPinhole(400,400,0,300,300,600,600);

    // Create the transform from pinhole to fisheye views
    LensDistortionNarrowFOV pinholeDistort = new LensDistortionPinhole(pinholeModel);
    LensDistortionWideFOV fisheyeDistort = new LensDistortionUniversalOmni(fisheyeModel);
    NarrowToWidePtoP_F32 transform = new NarrowToWidePtoP_F32(pinholeDistort,fisheyeDistort);

    // Load fisheye RGB image
    Planar<GrayU8> fisheyeImage = ConvertBufferedImage.convertFrom(
            image, true, ImageType.pl(3,GrayU8.class));

    // Create the image distorter which will render the image
    InterpolatePixel<Planar<GrayU8>> interp = FactoryInterpolation.
            createPixel(0, 255, InterpolationType.BILINEAR, BorderType.ZERO, fisheyeImage.getImageType());
    ImageDistort<Planar<GrayU8>,Planar<GrayU8>> distorter =
            FactoryDistort.distort(false,interp,fisheyeImage.getImageType());

    // Pass in the transform created above
    distorter.setModel(new PointToPixelTransform_F32(transform));
    // Render the image.  The camera will have a rotation of 0 and will thus be looking straight forward
    Planar<GrayU8> pinholeImage = fisheyeImage.createNew(pinholeModel.width, pinholeModel.height);
    distorter.apply(fisheyeImage,pinholeImage);
    BufferedImage bufferedPinhole0 = ConvertBufferedImage.convertTo(pinholeImage,null,true);

    distorter.apply(fisheyeImage,pinholeImage);
    BufferedImage bufferedPinhole1 = ConvertBufferedImage.convertTo(pinholeImage,null,true);

    return ConvertBufferedImage.convertTo(pinholeImage, null, true);
}
```